# diffrence output in chrome developer console and mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I developed a responsive web page by bootstrap & finally I want to test it ,
I tested it on the chrome developer console (F12) and everything seems good.
but when I see the result in the real mobile device I get shocked 
there was many  difference on that .
its seems that non of the my media screen object worked .

this is my website Url : http://5.61.25.90/~fares

Comment: Please consider being more specific and providing some code snippets. What exactly is displaying differently?

Comment: its seems good on the chrome developer console but in the real mobile device its seems that never do the responisve

Comment: you can check this url with pc and press f12 & after that check this with real mobile device

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the answer
I forget the use the viewport meta tag

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Without it the device assumes and sets the viewport to full size.